# What is wrong with this CancellationTokenSource example

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Anybody mind providing an opinion on whether or not this is a good or bad example of Task Cancellation and why. I have my own opinion and I've been told that its baseless, just trying to find out who is off base. I don't think its me, but I am okay with it being me. I just need to know its me so I can evolve if required.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ImportSource();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static void ImportSource()
    {
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
        var task1 = Task.Run(() => Import(token), token);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        // if we attempt to cancel the token
        CancelToken(cancellationTokenSource);
    }
    public static void CancelToken(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancellation in process!");
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
    static void Import(CancellationToken token)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            // check if the token is cancelled
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Token was cancelled");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Importing data is in process!");
                Import(token);
                i++;
            }
           
        } while (i < 1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Moved my last comment into body since trying not to influence the opinions isn't allowing for any traction. Here is where I am at with this code:

My biggest problem with the above code is that its not a good example of recursive+iterative cancellation. If you entirely delete the do loop, you get identical results and have a decent recursive cancellation example. On the other hand, the loop implementation could change to i<10, the recursive call could just be deleted and then you would have a decent example of iterative cancellation.

So, how could this be modified to be a very clear and meaningful example of both recursive+iteration cancellation, but still keep it as minimal as possible?

Comment: 1) Is this code you've written yourself? 2) If so, could you elaborate on what you think is the problem/ what area you're looking for feedback on - i.e. what does this code even do - what's the context. See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I want an unfiltered opinion of what you would think if I proposed the above program (which functions) as a "Task Cancellation Example". I have intentionally left out who wrote it and what my opinions are until I get some answers. I will eventually provide that, I just don't want to influence opinions at this point.

Comment: The academic answer: it depends. For example from the cooperative perspective it can be considered as good example. On the other hand from consequent / consistent point of view is bad because it's mixing `Thread`s and `Task`s. So, from what perspective are you looking for assessment?

Comment: From a demonstration perspective, which is exactly what this code is representing, I didn't even considered the mingling of Thread & Task as a problem. I will investigate the Task.Delay as a more coherent implementation.

Comment: The question still stands. What do you want to demonstrate with/about CancellationToken? The primary use case? The core concept? The chaining ability? The transfer for all the way down? The exception handling? The `Register` functionality? The `CanBeCanceled` usage? etc.

Comment: @Bogatitus Sorry but I'm a bit confused with this *example of both recursive+iteration cancellation* . An algorithm is usually either iterative or recursive. Are you looking for 2 examples?

Comment: Your confusion is understandable and the answer may be that 2 examples are required, but I was wanting to know if its possible to do both in a clear way. IE, threads being as unpredictable as they are, an ideal example would potentially terminate within the loop check or a recursive check, but not exclusively like the current example does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share with you my revised version in two parts.

### First part

```
static async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Application has been started");

    var cancellationSignal = new CancellationTokenSource();

    StartLongRunningOperationInBackground(cancellationSignal.Token);
    await CancelLongRunningOperationAfter(cancellationSignal);

    Console.WriteLine("Application has been finished");
}

public static void StartLongRunningOperationInBackground(CancellationToken token)
{
    _ = Task.Run(() => LongRunningIterativeOperation(token), token);

    Console.WriteLine("Long running operation has been started");
}

public static async Task CancelLongRunningOperationAfter(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource, int cancelAfterInMs = 500)
{
    await Task.Delay(cancelAfterInMs);
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    
    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation has been requested");
}
```

#### Changes

- I've moved the declaration of the `CancellationTokenSource` to the `Main`

  - With that the cooperative nature of cancellation tokens are more clear
- I've renamed the `ImportSource` to `StartLongRunningOperationInBackground`

  - I do believe that profound naming can help eligibility and understanding
- I've moved the waiting before the cancellation request into the `CancelLongRunningOperationAfter`

  - I think it increases cohesion because cancellation should be done after that period of time
  - So, they belong together
- I've discarded the result of the `Task.Run`

  - This is a fairly common way to express *fire and forget*

### Second part

```
private const int maxSteps = 100;
static void LongRunningIterativeOperation(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int currentStep = 0; currentStep < maxSteps; currentStep++)
    {
        //Simulate computation intensive code
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        //Simulate progress report
        Console.WriteLine($"Done: {currentStep + 1} / {maxSteps}");
    }
}

static void LongRunningRecursiveOperation(CancellationToken token, int currentStep = 0)
{
    if (currentStep == maxSteps) return;

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //Simulate computation intensive code
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    //Simulate progress report
    Console.WriteLine($"Done: {currentStep + 1} / {maxSteps}");

    LongRunningRecursiveOperation(token, currentStep + 1);
}
```

#### Changes

- I've created two versions of the same method

  - One which demonstrates the iterative approach
  - And another which does the same but in a recursive fashion
- I've used `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` instead of checking the `IsCancellationRequested`

  - If we don't need to do any cleanup then `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` is more cleaner solution
- I've used `Thread.Sleep` here intentionally

  - This is a blocking operation, which can be used to simulate CPU bound operation
  - It is in alignment with `Task.Run`, which is designed for CPU bound operations

Comment: Thank you Peter. FYI, I've been awake for about 22 hours and still have 7 more hours of obligations that have to be done today. I will analyze this as soon as I can, but it certainly looks interesting and I really appreciate the detailed explanations. Based on my quick review, are we are going with the theory that directly mangling the 2 types together with equal cancellation opportunity would generally be a bad use of the TPL? IE, I should pick a lane and parallelize that unit of work.

Comment: @Bogatitus To be honest with you I don't get your question. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Peter, those were very nice explanations and I learned a number of things from you. I think I'll end my quest to generically put both iterative and recursive cancellation "work" into the same task. I believe it is possible to demo them concurrently, but maybe not without one of them doing some degree of non-theoretical work.